How does "cifsacl" or "idsfromsid" w/ "modefromsid" work in CIFS/SMB? How do I use them to support Unix permissions on a Samba server?
I have a Samba server running FreeBSD and ZFS, and a Linux client who needs to mount a Samba share. To avoid compatibility problems, it should be mounted in a way that respects and supports Unix permissions on the client side. Based on my research, when mounting a Samba share using Linux's CIFS driver, there are 5 possible methods to handle Unix permissions:

Mount via uid=,gid=,dir_mode=,file_mode=.
Unix permissions are not supported in the base CIFS/SMB procotol, they can't be used on a plain SMB server without any extension. Thus, specifying these options will force the Linux CIFS driver to use default owners, groups and modes for all files, and they can't be changed.

Enable SMBv1 Unix extension via unix extensions = yes on Samba
In the past, HP defined a SMBv1 Unix extension. When SMBv1 Unix extension is used, owner, group, and mode information are automatically passed from the server to the Linux client's CIFS driver. As long as both the UID and GID are consistent on both the server and client, it should behave like a local Unix filesystem.
Unfortunately, SMBv1 is insecure and has been deprecated for many years, making this option unusable. Perhaps it can still be used within a private VPN, but I really don't want to use this obsolete option.

Enable SMBv3 POSIX extension via smb3 unix extensions = yes, mount via posix
Recently, development work has been done to implement a new POSIX extension for SMBv3, which allows Unix permissions and other features. Unfortunately, while the posix option has already been added to Linux's CIFS driver, but Samba support remains experimental and requires a development build, so it can't be used on production systems.

ACL permission mapping via cifsacl, server-enforced.

NFS-style permission mapping via idsfromsid, modefromsid, client enforced.


According to various developer presentations from 2020, the Linux CIFS driver supports Option 4 and 5 to enable Unix permissions via mapping from ACL or SID, controlled by the mounting option cifsacl, idsfromsid, and modefromsid. These features are said to be production-ready. Some posts also mentioned that cifsacl is server-enforced, and often used together with idmap, while idsfromsid and modefromsid uses a NFS-style client-enforced permission model, which is the simpler option for single-user share.
Unfortunately, it seems that almost no documentation exists for cifsacl, idsfromsid and modefromsid although these features had been developed 4 years ago. There are only a couple of mentions about these options from developer conference presentations, but very little is known by the public For example, the official kernel.org documentation only has a mysterious statement, but without any explanation about how to use them correctly:

Recommendations: To improve security the SMB2.1 dialect or later (usually will get SMB3.1.1) is now the new default. [...] There are additional mount options that may be helpful for SMB3 to get improved POSIX behavior (NB: can use vers=3 to force SMB3 or later, never 2.1): mfsymlinks and either cifsacl or modefromsid (usually with idsfromsid)

When I tried adding idsfromsid and modefromsid to my mount options, it doesn't seem to work. If the mount command is executed as root, all files inside the mounting point are still owned by root rather than actual user on the server. The modes for these files can't be changed, even by root. The behavior seems identical to plain CIFS/SMB without any extension.
Question

How does cifsacl work in CIFS/SMB?
How does idsfromsid and modefromsid work in CIFS/SMB?
How do I use them correctly? I'm particularly interested in using the idsfromsid and modefromsid method, as it looks simpler.

Bibliography

The Linux kernel user’s and administrator’s guide » CIFS » Usage

SMB3.1.1 POSIX/Linux Extensions - Steven French

SMB3.1.1 POSIX Protocol Extensions: Summary and Current Implementation Status

Linux Access to the Cloud and NAS reborn: Recent progress in SMB3.1.1

The Future of Accessing Files remotely from Linux: SMB3.1.1 update

CIFS mount options supported

[Samba] How to turn on SMB3 POSIX extensions in Samba server?



By reading the Linux kernel source code, I think I've solved one piece of the puzzle.


How does idsfromsid and modefromsid work in CIFS/SMB?

In SMB, each user or group has its own SID, which is used for access control. These users are managed by Samba tools like pdbedit or smbpasswd. This is different from Unix accounts managed by Unix tools like passwd or useradd.
Using Samba, one can view the ACL of a file or directory via:
$ smbcacls //server/share /dir -U user

For example, the following command lists the ACL of the root directory of //server/share. Samba ACLs are stored as Unix filesystem ACL (POSIX draft ACL or NFSv4 ACL) of the underlying file system, which may or may not be meaningful under Unix. But there are always three ACL special entries for User, Group, and Everyone, which match the Unix permissions.
$ smbcacls //server/share / -U user
Password for [WORKGROUP\user]:
REVISION:1
CONTROL:SR|DP
OWNER:SERVER\user
GROUP:Unix Group\user
ACL:SERVER\user:ALLOWED/0x0/0x001e01ff
ACL:Unix Group\user:ALLOWED/0x0/READ
ACL:Everyone:ALLOWED/0x0/READ

In the output, OWNER:SERVER\user means the owner of the file is a Samba user, and GROUP:Unix Group\user means the group of the file is a Unix group. Why is there a difference?
When a Unix user has a corresponding Samba account, the Samba server automatically maps the Unix account to that Samba account. But when an user or group is unknown to Samba, special SIDs are used as placeholders for unmapped Unix accounts.
This can be made clearly by inspecting the raw SIDs in its numeric format:
$ smbcacls //server/share / -U user --numeric
Password for [WORKGROUP\user]:
REVISION:1
CONTROL:0x8004
OWNER:S-1-5-21-3329942186-90701280-2335022555-1001
GROUP:S-1-22-2-1002
ACL:S-1-5-21-3329942186-90701280-2335022555-1001:0/0x0/0x001e01ff
ACL:S-1-22-2-1002:0/0x0/0x001200a9
ACL:S-1-1-0:0/0x0/0x001200a9

Note that the Owner is a real SID S-1-5-21-3329942186-90701280-2335022555-1001, 1001 matches the Samba user ID in pdbedit -L -v. But the Group has a special placeholder SID S-1-22-2-1002, 1002 matches the underlying Unix group ID.
For another example, let's examine a file controlled by a Unix user and group that Samba doesn't know anything about:
# smbcacls //server/share / -U user --numeric
Password for [WORKGROUP\user]:
REVISION:1
CONTROL:0x8004
OWNER:S-1-22-1-1009
GROUP:S-1-22-2-1010
ACL:S-1-22-1-1009:0/0x0/0x001e01ff
ACL:S-1-22-2-1010:0/0x0/0x001200a9
ACL:S-1-1-0:0/0x0/0x001200a9

Thus, it becomes obvious that:

SID S-1-22-1-uid is a reserved Samba SID to represent an unmapped Unix user.

SID S-1-22-2-gid is a reserved Samba SID to represent an unmapped Unix group.


This is exactly how idsfromsid works. According to the Linux source code, when idsfromsid is set, CIFS driver will map all files on the remote server with SID S-1-22-1-uid and S-1-22-1-gid to a local Unix user with the same uid and gid. Another convention originally used by Windows, S-1-5-88-1-uid / S-1-5-88-2-gid, are also recognized.
/* See See http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh509017(v=ws.10).aspx */
static void setup_owner_group_sids(char *buf)
{
    struct owner_group_sids *sids = (struct owner_group_sids *)buf;

    /* Populate the user ownership fields S-1-5-88-1 */
    sids->owner.Revision = 1;
    sids->owner.NumAuth = 3;
    sids->owner.Authority[5] = 5;
    sids->owner.SubAuthorities[0] = cpu_to_le32(88);
    sids->owner.SubAuthorities[1] = cpu_to_le32(1);
    sids->owner.SubAuthorities[2] = cpu_to_le32(current_fsuid().val);

    /* Populate the group ownership fields S-1-5-88-2 */
    sids->group.Revision = 1;
    sids->group.NumAuth = 3;
    sids->group.Authority[5] = 5;
    sids->group.SubAuthorities[0] = cpu_to_le32(88);
    sids->group.SubAuthorities[1] = cpu_to_le32(2);
    sids->group.SubAuthorities[2] = cpu_to_le32(current_fsgid().val);
}

Furthermore, according to the Linux kernel source code, modefromsid works similarly.  It uses a reserved SID S-1-5-88-3-mode to record Unix permissions. This ACL entry is read and translated to Unix permissions by Linux CIFS client, and it's also updated when the Unix permissions of a file is changed.
A full list of recognized special SIDs are:
/* S-1-22-1 Unmapped Unix users */
static const struct smb_sid sid_unix_users = {1, 1, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22},
        {cpu_to_le32(1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };

/* S-1-22-2 Unmapped Unix groups */
static const struct smb_sid sid_unix_groups = { 1, 1, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 22},
        {cpu_to_le32(2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };

/*
 * See https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh509017(v=ws.10).aspx
 */

/* S-1-5-88 MS NFS and Apple style UID/GID/mode */

/* S-1-5-88-1 Unix uid */
static const struct smb_sid sid_unix_NFS_users = { 1, 2, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5},
    {cpu_to_le32(88),
     cpu_to_le32(1), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };

/* S-1-5-88-2 Unix gid */
static const struct smb_sid sid_unix_NFS_groups = { 1, 2, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5},
    {cpu_to_le32(88),
     cpu_to_le32(2), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };

/* S-1-5-88-3 Unix mode */
static const struct smb_sid sid_unix_NFS_mode = { 1, 2, {0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 5},
    {cpu_to_le32(88),
     cpu_to_le32(3), 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0} };

Workaround

When I tried adding idsfromsid and modefromsid to my mount options, it doesn't seem to work. If the mount command is executed as root, all files inside the mounting point are still owned by root rather than actual user on the server. The modes for these files can't be changed, even by root. The behavior seems identical to plain CIFS/SMB without any extension.

After discovering the theory of operation of idsfromsid, I've found the root cause too. The problem occurs if the Samba server knows about the Unix account. In this case, a real Samba SID rather than a placeholder will be granted permissions in the ACL (manually changing the owner to the reserved SID via smbcacls doesn't seem to work, as it's still getting mapped back to its real SID by Samba). In this case, Linux kernel is unable to map the SID as a local Unix account, and idsfromsid fails.
One can confirm it by enabling debugging on the CIFS client:
# echo "module cifs +p" > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control 
# echo "module cifs/* +p" > /sys/kernel/debug/dynamic_debug/control 
# echo 7 > /proc/fs/cifs/cifsFYI 
# dmesg | grep cifsacl
CIFS: fs/smb/client/cifsacl.c: sid_to_id: Can't map SID os:S-1-5-21-3329942186-90701280-2335022555-1002 to a uid
CIFS: fs/smb/client/cifsacl.c: Unix UID 1009 returned from SID

Thus, after knowing its theory of operation, I found one way to use idsfromsid is the following hack:

Create a Samba user user.
Change the filesystem permission of the shared directory to an unrelated Unix user and Unix group that Samba doesn't know anything about, such as unixuser, unixgroup.
Use force user unixuser and force group unixgroup in smb.conf so all files created under this fileshare will remain to be owned by unixuser and unixgroup (you may also need additional filesystem-level permission to grant access to unixuser and unixgroup).
Create the same unixuser and unixgroup on the Linux CIFS client, manually change the UID and GID so they match the Samba server.
Mount the fileshare using the Samba account user, with the option idsfromsid, then use the file inside it as unixuser (on the client). Now all file owners and groups should get properly mapped automatically.

This way, all files under the Linux CIFS client mountpoint will have the correct user and group ownership. In addition, so far I'm still unable to get modefromsid working. The Unix file modes are not respected and can't be changed.
Upon further research, I found Samba ignores and appears to actively strips NFS SIDs, as seen here smbd: ignore set NTACL requests which contain S-1-5-88 NFS ACEs. This is why permissions can't be changed. Overall, it seems like this configuration is not fully supported by Samba.

Of course, this hack (in particular, step 2 and 3) is abusive, and is probably not what developers had in mind. But due to lack of documentation, this is the best I could do...
Hopefully one day the community will get everything documented properly...

Update: I posted this question on the Samba mailing list, Samba developer Rowland Penny told me that:

I think that while Samba might accept patches to get 'S-1-5-88' to work, I fear that any NFSv4 ACLs patches will only be accepted after the Linux kernel accepts them. At present (unless someone knows different), NFSv4 ACLs only work on freebsd etc and not on Linux.

Thus, unless I got anything wrong, the conclusion is: Unix permission emulation features idsfromsid, and modefromsid are not supported in Samba right now, because the required S-1-5-88 ACLs are unrecognized by Samba. Because they're discarded, permission emulation won't work.
But it shouldn't be too difficult to patch Samba to accept them, and perhaps the Samba team is even open to upstreaming theses patches (NFSv4 ACL is only one way to implement Samba ACL, not the only way, so the lack support is not a blocker).

Wow! What an awesome bit of research. Thanks for sharing!
